# docker exec redirect stdout to host files

Tags: docker

I run a python script inside a docker and this script is printing some informations.

I wish to write this logs to a file(on my host system).

I try to do it like this:

```
( docker exec docker_1 /bin/bash -c 'cd folder && python3 run.py') >  ./logs/test.txt
```

But the file test.txt dosn't exist. I think that the file is being created inside my docker. But i want it outside from it!

Comment: What version of docker? What host OS? What you're trying should work fine, and *does* work on my system with version `17.05.0-ce` running under Linux.

Comment: I am using docker 17.09.0-ce with ubunto 16.04

Comment: Are you sure run.py is returning data? You might want to edit the question to include both the contents of run.py and your Dockerfile.

Comment: My original run.py is very big... ;) I have create a test.py script that have only one line "print('test')" and it's working!
I don't know why my big script isn't returning anything...

Comment: Now it is working... really strange! Thank you for your help!